# Crashlytics's Initialize the SDK does not work

Tags: ios, crashlytics

I am trying to implement Crashlytics to my current iOS app, but Crashlytics doesn't go further after Initializing the SDK. Every app before works fine, but now it doesn't.

Can you please tell me, what is wrong with this? Every line of code is in my app. I do the same steps but nothing has happened.

Thank you.[image]

Comment: Is Crashlytics Framework properly included?

Comment: Yes, it is in Build Phases, included in AppDelegate file.

Comment: It helps closing and restarting XCode. I have also had this issue a few times.

Comment: Also make sure you are logged into Crashlytics in the Crashlytics app and that you run the app on a iOS device instead of Simulator.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue. Tow days of manipulation. It was an "very odd" trouble on Crashlytics side. I contacted with support and engineer fixed this in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing and reinstalling the Crashlytics app *and* framework.

That fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Even I'm using Swift I had to choose Objective-C in the crashlytics dropdown, to be able to complete the Initialization of the SDK.
After that I've pressed Cmd+R to run the project and it worked.